# Jolokia returns "HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized" in Opendaylight when trying to set up clustering

Tags: opendaylight, jolokia

I am trying to set up clustering in Opendaylight, just as described at the [Documentation page](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/getting-started-guide/clustering.html). When I try to monitor the clustering status using Jolokia, ODL responds with a 401 unauthorized error. Does Jolokia have a specific *username* and *password* or does it still use admin/admin?

The commands I am using to query ODL are:

`curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://10.5.1.201:8181/jolokia/list`

or

`curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://10.5.1.201:8181/jolokia/read/org.opendaylight.controller:type=DistributedConfigDatastore,Category=ShardManager,name=shard-manager-config`

And the error message I receive is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/jolokia/list</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.jolokia.osgi.servlet.JolokiaServlet</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have continued working on setting up clustering in ODL, and I have found that the Error 401 message posted before displays whenever something is not correctly configured. So it is not strictly a lack of a correct username and password, but a standard message when something goes wrong. For future reference, I provide the following advice:

1. Do not use the `configure_cluster.sh` script to generate the `akka.conf`, `module-shards.conf` and `modules.conf` files. It is better to modify them manually, although the script may be used as a reference.
2. Remember that the cluster machines try to connect with each other when ODL starts executing. So it is a good idea to start the machines at the same time.

I hope this helps.